# Important question please read this

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

if my internet service provider (ISP) can see I visit sites that I use the Tor browser?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. The encrypted packet tor sends goes to a tor relay, which goes to another, etc. Each relay only knows the one before it and the one after it in the chain. Your isp could not see what sites you visit.

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous. It's possible he meant "Can my ISP see that I'm visiting sites using the Tor browser?", in which case the answer would be "yes".

Comment: true. the question this is a duplicate of is the other interpretation though